# Reset Webots Position Sensor

Tags: webots

I want a webots robot to move forward and then rotate 90 degrees clockwise in exactly the same manner 4 times to go around a square. The robot will do the first leg perfectly but I can not figure out how to reset the position sensor to 0 at the end of the loop. Any ideas?

```
for i in range (0, 4):
    leftWheelSensor.getValue()
    rightWheelSensor.getValue()
    robot.step(800)
    leftWheel.setPosition(21.4)
    rightWheel.setPosition(21.4)
    leftWheel.setPosition(21.4 + 2.6)
    rightWheel.setPosition(21.4 - 2.6)
```

Right here I should be able to set the left and right wheel sensor back to zero but there doesn't seem to be anyway to do it. I tried to disable and re enable the sensor but that didn't work. Here is the webots info about the class...

class PositionSensor (Device):
    ROTATIONAL, LINEAR

```
def enable(self, samplingPeriod):
def disable(self):
def getSamplingPeriod(self):
def getValue(self):
def getType(self):
# ...
```

Comment: Your program looks odd as I would expect that you actually retrieve the value of the position sensor with for example `left_position = leftWheelSensor.getValue()` and then use this information to compute the new target position of a motor. Moreover setting a wheel position several times without calling `robot.step` in between is useless. You should probably follow the Webots tutorials to better understand how controllers work.

Comment: Thank you so much - and yes I am doing those now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible from the Webots API to reset the position sensor value.

However, you can easily compute an offset in your controllers, e.g.:

```
for i in range (0, 4):
    leftWheel.setPosition(21.4)
    rightWheel.setPosition(21.4)
    robot.step(800)
    leftOffset = leftWheelSensor.getValue()
    rightOffset = rightWheelSensor.getValue()
    leftWheel.setPosition(leftOffset + 2.6)
    rightWheel.setPosition(rightOffset - 2.6)
    robot.step(800)
```

Comment: Thank you for the info!